Spring event transaction handling
I have 2 spring events eventA & eventB with order 1 & 2 respectively to be executed. In case any of the event (A/B) throws exception, the data written by eventA & eventB to be rolled back. The events are published with transaction annotation.
Publisher code:
@Transactional
    private void publishEvent(Order order){
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(order);
    }

Event Listener
 @org.springframework.core.annotation.Order(1)
 @EventListener
 @Transactional(propagation =Propagation.NESTED)
 public void eventA(Order order){
   //DB write
 }



@org.springframework.core.annotation.Order(2)
 @EventListener
 @Transactional(propagation =Propagation.NESTED)
 public void eventB(Order order){
  //DB write
 }

Have tried with TransactionalEventListener also, but not able to solve the same.

And the problem here is? Also NESTED is probably not what you think it is.

The problem is rollback is not working

For starters the @Transactional on the private method is useless it should be on the method that is calling this. Due to no transaction each listener will be invoked in each a dedicated transaction instead of a single one.

@M.Deinum making the publishEvent as public does not help. Is there any other approach to handle this for my problem

Making it public won't help because it is an intrenal method call. I stated that it should be on the method that is calling that method.
